How to mock AdminGuard NestJS function in Jest?
here is how i connect all this stuff for test
const mockAdminGuard = {
    canActivate: jest.fn(() => true),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [UsersController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UsersService,
          useValue: mockUsersService,
        },
        {
          provide: AdminGuard,
          useValue: mockAdminGuard,
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

here is test which is not mocking guard
(response is undefined, but i don't receive 403 error and message: forbidden resource as in postman request)
describe('getUser', () => {
    it('should return error when request is not from admin', async () => {
      mockAdminGuard.canActivate.mockImplementationOnce(() => false);

      const response = await usersService.findOne('userid');

      expect(response).toBe(123123123);
    });
  }

here is controller
@UseGuards(AdminGuard)
  @Get(':id')
  async getUser(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<User> {
    return await this.usersService.findOne(id);
  }

here is admin guard
@Injectable()
export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  async canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = await User.findOne({where: { id: request.user.sub}});

    // Return a boolean indicating if the user has the 'admin' role
    return user && user.role === 'admin';
  }
}

everything works fine for requests, but i cant figure out how to write test for this one
P.S. tests just passing, when should be failed
here is test with broken expectations
Expected: 123123123
Received: {"email": "userone@example.com", "id": "userid", "name": "User One"}

  78 |       const response = await usersService.findOne('userid');
  79 |
> 80 |       expect(response).toBe(123123123);
     |                        ^
  81 |     });
  82 |   });
  83 | });


You can mock User.findOne alternatively. Generally, I'd advocate for not mocking at all and just running the test against an in memory db, but that might be a bit much outside of your setup. Less mocks the better.

Your test title is inaccurate anyway, it doesn't test if the user is an admin or not, it just tests your controller uses the guard that you're mocking.

but how to test adminGuard then? or what`s the pattern. if i have route like getUser(id), and it is protected by adminGuard what is the proper way to test? test both, is adminGuard works and is getUser  works, or just to tests controllers and do not test adminGuard in any way?

Don't think about "proper" ways to do things, there's too many and too many opinions. If you're looking for a "proper" way, it'll hold you back. Testing AdminGuard is a good idea, and testing that routes that require admins are restricted to users with admin roles (but not by mocking AdminGuard, as that's an implementaton detail of how those routes are protected, imo) is also a good idea. If you aim for "less mocks", you'll write better tests. That doesn't mean "no mocks ever", it's all a balance. Test and assert on the behaviour, not the implementation

then can you give me example how to test route that require admin role? i get the idea, but i still don't know how to do that in code)
